# Python: If (user_input) in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

Having an issue with checking if user input is in a dictionary.

Basics of program is there's a shop inventory. The items are stored in a dictionary with corresponding values e.g. `{'kettle': 3,.....}`

Then I want user to write what they want. So if the user has entered 'kettle' I want to remove the item from the shop inventory and put in user inventory.

The main problem right now is just getting an if statement together. This is what I'm trying:

```
user_choice = input('What would you like to buy? ')
if user_choice in shop_inventory:
    print('Complete')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

How can I get the program to print "Complete"?

Comment: What is wrong with this code? If the dictionary contains 'kettle', and the user inputs that value, this will print 'Complete'.

Comment: This code works

Comment: Under py2 you'll have to use `raw_input`, not `input` as `input` evaluates the inputted data as python code. So you'll have to enter `'kettle'` with single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pop()` to remove the item from the `shop_inventory`.

```
shop_inventory =  {'kettle': 3}
user_choice = input('What would you like to buy? ')
if user_choice in shop_inventory:
    shop_inventory.pop(user_choice)
    print(shop_inventory)
    print('Complete')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

Answer (score -4):

Instead of `input()`, use `raw_input`:

```
user_choice = raw_input('What would you like to buy? ')
if user_choice in shop_inventory:
    print('Complete')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

**Explanation:**
In **Python 2**, `raw_input()` returns a string, and `input()` tries to run the input as a Python expression.

In **Python 3** there is only `raw_input()`. It was renamed in `input()`.

[As statet here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Comment: What's a high comma?

Comment: quotes. Edited it..  @Kevin

Comment: @Kevin I edited it. Could you please remove your downvote?

Comment: There's nothing to remove, because I never downvoted you to begin with :-)

Comment: @Kevin I did not want to be mean, but I got punished for answers I wrote last year and the only way to become active again is to remove the downvotes. Maybe StackOverflow has no space for change..